# Read a tab delimited table into R, where first line is column names preceded by a #

Tags: r

I have a tab delimited .txt file. The first line of the file is the column names, 
preceded by a `#` character. It looks like this:

```
#SampleID   BarcodeSequence LinkerPrimerSequence    PlateLocation   Plate   sampleMaterial  DateLoaded  nucleicAcidProtocolID   kitLotID    extractionDate  processed
BCPER.001.21.M.1.6.20140715scriptATAACGGTGTAC   GTGTGYCAGCMGCCGCGGTAA   B12 NEON_Plate_5_12-18-14   soil    1/8/15  PowerSoil96WellExtractionv1.pdf PS14K4  20141218    Ti
CPER.001.21.M.7.5.20140715ER.001CGCAAGCCCGCG1407GTGTGYCAGCMGCCGCGGTAA   C02 NEON_Plate_5_12-18-14   soil    1/8/15  PowerSoil96WellExtractionv1.pdf PS14K4  20141218    Ti
CPER.001.21.M.9.17.20140715R.001GTCGTTACCCGC1407GTGTGYCAGCMGCCGCGGTAA   C01 NEON_Plate_5_12-18-14   soil    1/8/15  PowerSoil96WellExtractionv1.pdf PS14K4  20141218    Ti
CPER.001.M.10.6.20131218CPER.001GCCGCGGGATCA0140GTGTGYCAGCMGCCGCGGTAA   f08 NEON_Plate_7_1-16-15    soil    1/19/15 PowerSoil96WellExtractionv1.pdf PS14K4  20150116    Ti
```

I could manually go into these files and remove this line. But I would really like to use `read.table` to read these files, without modifying them from their original condition. This way I have a clean record of all my data manipulation.

Comment: Perhaps set `skip = 1` when using `read.table`,

Comment: You could set the first line to be the column names with `header=TRUE`

Comment: I would just fix it with `gsub` afterwards. `names(df) <- gsub("#", "", names(df), fixed=TRUE)`

Comment: @emilliman5 yeah, this doesn't work because the first line is a hash.

Comment: @ycw this skips the header line entirely.

Comment: @Mako212 the problem is it won't read in the first line at all because of the hash. So, I can't go in and gsub it out.

Comment: Doesn't work in what way? Are you receiving an error?

Comment: @emilliman5 no, the header is just the first line of the data, rather than the actual column names in the file that have a `#` preceding them.

Comment: Try `read.delim("myfile", check.names = FALSE)`  If that still has a problem then add skip = 1 and read the first line separately in a read.table call. with argument `nrows = 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a built in way to deal with this using the `comment.char` option in `read.table`. Set `comment.char = ""` to ignore the comment `#` and you should read in your data set fine, provided there are not other commented lines that need to stay commented.

```
data <- read.table('/path/to/file.txt',sep='\t' ,header=T, comment.char = "")
```